# CakePHP 1.3: How to display form validation error messages when form is not tied to models?

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a view where I used FormHelper methods (`$this->Form->input`, etc.) to create a form (post), but this form is not tied to any model.  It's a dumb form.

For example, some fields are date fields.  My controller will do some validation on these fields, but if there is a problem, how would I display the error message right below the field that had a validation error?  With forms tied to models, CakePHP will automagically add a div to the relevant field to display the validation error message.  Is there something similar for dumb forms?

Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: I think the easiest way is to make the form tied to a model.  You can make a model that is not tied to a table, and only exists for data validation, so the only thing in it would be data validation rules.  Then rather than doing the validation in the controller like you said, call $model->valdiates($data); to validate it.  

The other possible way to do it is to manually get $model->validitionErrors after attempting to save the relevant models, and then doing what you need to with them.

Comment: The form has five fields, so I'm being told it isn't worth it to tie it to a model.  Can I use something like $this->Form->error()?

Comment: I believe $this->Form->error() will only return something if there was a validation error through the normal means.  You can manually set a validation error message, by setting the appropriate values in the array $this->Form->validationErrors, where $this->Form is the FormHelper.  Its formatting is the same as $model->validationErrors.

Comment: Tip: Forms should pretty much always be tied to a model. Rewrite your code so that the question is "How to display form validation error messages when the _model_ is not tied to a table" and there will be no question (OR: see ADmad's answer).

Comment: In creating a dummy model, CakePHP will look for a controller named "Dummy." I need the form to go to an existing controller's method, not the "Dummy" controller.  My $this->FormHelper->create() is set to 'false' as the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a model which isn't associated with a db table. Rest will be same as using a regular db backed model. Eg:

```
// Model
class Dummy extends Model {
   public $useTable = false;
   public $validate = array('somefield' => 'notEmpty');
}


// View
echo $this->Form->create('Dummy');
echo $this->Form->input('somefield');
......

// Controller
public some_action() {
    //if post request
    $this->Dummy->set($this->request->data);
    $this->Dummy->validates();
}
```

Comment: In creating a dummy model, CakePHP will look for a controller named "Dummy."  I need the form to go to an existing controller's method, not the "Dummy" controller.

Comment: I'm going to accept this as the answer, as its becoming apparent that CakePHP really wants you to use models for forms generated by FormHelper.  While I could try other solutions, they are a little awkward.

Comment: Using a "Dummy" model doesn't mean you need a "DummyController" too. Just use whatever controller you are currently using. Just use `$this->loadModel('Dummy')` in your action before trying to validate. Specify the `url` option in `Form->create()` if it's POSTing to DummyController.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know I could just load a model before validating.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What about FormHelper::error() ?

http://api.cakephp.org/1.3/class-FormHelper.html#_error